# How can I stop iOS from substituting emoji icons for some Unicode characters?

Tags: ios, font, bug, unicode

On iOS I'm getting bizarre (and mostly goofy) icon glyphs substituted for the glyphs that I expect — and see as expected on macOS — for many fonts.

For example, if I enter a ["Black Right-Pointing Triangle"](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25B6) in various fonts on macOS (here Open Sans, Avenir, and Book Antiqua) I get, as expected

[image]

but on iOS I get

[image]

I understand that glyphs, especially emoji, can change depending on many things (platform, font, OS, etc.) but the substitution of crazy icons for standard characters in common fonts shared between macOS and iOS clearly wrong. For example, it ruins the UI of apps that rely on the correct glyphs, as in [Ncalc](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ncalc-graphing-calculator-84/id1509489130) for example:

[image]

How can I manage things when iOS substitutes goofy icons for some Unicode characters?

---

macOS 11.4; iOS 14.7.1

Comment: Asking why Apple does anything is generally off topic. Given that Apple did this, what are you trying to do? (That edit might make this on topic)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a human made a decision to ship this font / design. Why they did it is likely opinion based and definitely off topic here.

Comment: @bmike Apple does this intentionally? If so then the question isn’t so much why (the answer to which is clear) but how to repair it.

Comment: Wouldn’t the apps have to draw the shape themselves or implement specific code to avoid using the system defaults?

Comment: @bmike Saying that a human made this decision shows a deep ignorance of Apple’s internal workings.

Comment: Are you saying they accidentally shipped this or a robot made the call? I’ll let the other mods clear this up. The reviewers can vote to reopen now or if you choose to edit it.

Comment: For info on the Unicode rules for whether such characters are displayed as text or emoji, see https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-style.html

Comment: @bmike Of course I'm not saying a "robot made the call". I'm just stating the obvious: that saying it is a "human made" decision hugely overstates individual (and thus presumably legitimate, benevolent, etc.) agency in a culture that is actually hyper-corporate and and instrumental and regulated.

Comment: Does the iOS device HAVE the other two fonts?  I *think* iOS may ship with Open Sans.  If it does not, then it is going to substitute from another font it *does* have, same as the Mac would.  You assume with no evidence that a deliberate decision is made to substitute the glyph you like with the one you do not like, vs the normal font resolution process being used.

Comment: @MarcWilson Actually I don't assume that (but thank you for assuming that). That's bmike's doing. If it's in fact true that those fonts are not present, then that could be an answer to this question:The app where I'm selecting Avenir for example, isn't providing a glyph for that character, so it is being grabbed from some default place where the silly ones live.

Comment: @orome the "silly ones" all live in the Apple Color Emoji font.  If that font were absent or disabled, most apps would find some font which has the non-emoji version of the character and display it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Color_Emoji

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the edits and help to make this a “How” and not “Why” post…